# How to effectively handle the arguments when calling a generic function

Tags: c, function, dry

I am trying to figure out what's the most efficient way to solve the following problem using C.

Let's consider a generic function

```
void foo(int x, int y);
```

Normally, the function would be called as follow:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = foo(a, b);
```

However, in my code I must use a `genericCall` function declared as:

```
int genericCall(void (*func)(void *), void *args, size_t size);
```

So for example, in order to execute the code above I must introduce an auxiliary function and a struct:

```
// Define a struct to store the arguments
struct foo_args {
    int x;
    int y;
}

// Auxiliary function
void foo_aux(void *args) {
    struct foo_args *args;
    int x, y;

    // Unpack the arguments
    args = (struct foo_args *) args;
    x = args->x;
    y = args->y;

    // Invocation of the original function
    foo(x, y);
}

// ...

// Pack the arguments in the struct
struct foo_args args;
args.x = 1;
args.y = 2;

// Call the generic function
genericCall(foo_aux, &args, sizeof(struct foo_args));
```

As you can imagine this approach does not scale very well: every time I want to call a different function I must add a lot of  code that does very little apart from handling the arguments.

Is there a way to do the same without replicating all the code?

Thanks!

Comment: an elaborate set of macros? BTW, `foo_aux` can be simply `foo(((struct foo_args *)args)->x, ((struct foo_args *)args)->y)` and with a `typedef` even shorter.

Comment: Why not just `foo ((struct foo_args *)args->x, (struct foo_args *)args->y);`?

Comment: I do not understand how you can do args = (struct foo_args *) args; inside the foo_aux. Because you want it to be generic so it can have any type. Passing size from genericCall(foo_aux, &args, sizeof(struct foo_args));  wont help inside the foo_aux

Comment: No need to cast `args`, `void*` pointers convert flawlessly into any kind of pointer.

Comment: Check out https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constructing-Calls.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I understand that I can reduce the number of lines of my aux function, but it seems to not be trivial how to remove it entirely. I'll have a though about the usage of macros. Also, thanks for the link Jonathon!

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not much more that you can do. Your generic interface doesn't permit to pass type information, and if you have a function with multiple arguments that you want to pass, you have to place them to be accessible through a single pointer.

This is e.g how coding with thread interfaces (POSIX or C11) usually works.

Comment: Would it be possible to improve things if I had the possibility to change the interface of `genericCall`?

Comment: @Muffo, if you can change your generic function to receive `va_args` arguments through `...` and if you would be willing to have the functions that you pass in receive `va_list` as single argument, you could. But this becomes ugly very quickly, has some caveats because unexpected type conversions, and is quite inefficient if called often.

Comment: Would be different, if `genericCall` could be a macro. Would that be allowed?

Comment: I had a thought about using `...` but, as you suggested, I would also need to modify the functions to receive a single arguments. Also, the performance is quite important for the particular application. Would you improve things by using a macro instead?

Comment: @Muffo, macros with `...` are more efficient, since the replacement takes place a compile time. `va_arg` is inefficient, because it transform a static problem at compile time into a dynamic one that does counting and type conversion back and forth at run time. To say more, we would need to know much more, and this would clearly go beyond the scope of this question.